# Why is the type not inferred to be a union, but just one of the types?

Tags: typescript

I have a class:

```js
class Cancelled {
    static cancelled = new Cancelled()
    static from<T>(v: T | undefined) {
        return v ?? this.cancelled
    }
}
```

Why does VSCode infer the return type of `Cancelled.from` as only `Cancelled` instead of `T | Cancelled`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why Vscode infers the type of the result of the function Cancelled.from as only Cencelled instead of T | Cancelled?

Because at the moment, `Cancelled` doesn't define any non-static properties. That means it's compatible with almost anything. In the following code, the only lines that complain are the null and undefined:

```
const a: Cancelled = true;
const b: Cancelled = {};
const c: Cancelled = "hi";
const d: Cancelled = 3;
const e: Cancelled = new Date();
const f: Cancelled = () => {};
const g: Cancelled = Symbol('foo');
const h: Cancelled = null; // Error
const i: Cancelled = undefined; // Error
```

But your code excludes null and undefined, so we can ignore them. What we're left with is that `Cancelled` is a broader type than `NonNullable<T>`. Everything that is a `NonNullable<T>` is also a `Cancelled`, so saying `Cancelled | NonNullable<T>` is redundant. VS code shows the simpler type.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYDtgFMQmQE2gbwFDQOggBcxiBLYaYRFNTaAXmgWQHc5bV0MAKASnyESZStABmAJwD2AWwA8AFQB8vAG4AuaIugAfaAFcEGZOPKsM-HEMKFJyYgckJoa6AH530YgAtyEADoaJG5MG2gAX1wo3FxgaQQSaDAteBD6LGZiSQNkAG44hKSAI1SuDKYcCIL4xOJqMvSeSoAiPxaaovqMRrpm5gBmTrroZF7QzJZ2aAARMmQBYaTxcYrmASZlKqX6gHNV-ugAZQBPWWLpEF4AcnFpaWv+HegfA4ZmBAM0POgAel-oABRSQySSFEbkN6TIwmMwWH7-IEg6SSIA)

As soon as you add even one property to `Cancelled`, this is no longer the case, and the return type will be inferred to be `Cancelled | NonNullable<T>`.

```
class Cancelled {
    static cancelled = new Cancelled()
    static from<T>(v: T | undefined) {
        return v ?? this.cancelled
    }

    foo: string = 'bar'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDCYDtgFMQmQE2gbwFDQOggBcxiBLYaYRFNTaAXmgWQHc5bV0MAKASnyESZStABmAJwD2AWwA8AFQB8vAG4AuaIugAfaAFcEGZOPKsM-HEMKFJyYgckJoa6AH530YgAtyEADoaJG5MG2gAX1xw8WlpLRJJcwBzJmgAcgAjMEl03AigA)